# Failed Linking Google API in Android Application

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm using the Java Google APIs for an Android application.  I followed the usage pattern described here for Authenication and API use: http://goo.gl/rPZ9Z

The problem I'm having is that the call to GoogleTransport.create() throws a NoClassDefFoundException.  I looked at the log and the HttpHeaders class is not linking properly.  I attached the Google API JAR file using the normal method in eclipse and all other classes I'm using are working correctly.  Problem is that this one class in particular is not linked correctly.  Here are some logs of the app running but not calling the class:

01-27 14:04:34.390: WARN/dalvikvm(422): Link of class 'Lcom/google/api/client/http/HttpHeaders;' failed

01-27 14:04:34.400: WARN/dalvikvm(422): Unable to resolve superclass of Lcom/google/api/client/googleapis/GoogleHeaders; (43)

Log of direct call to GoogleTransport.create():

01-27 16:13:11.882: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16086): java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.google.api.client.http.HttpHeaders
01-27 16:13:11.882: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16086):     at com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport.(HttpTransport.java:145)
01-27 16:13:11.882: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(16086):     at com.google.api.client.googleapis.GoogleTransport.create(GoogleTransport.java:58)

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is this happening on the emulator?

Comment: Yes it is!  My code doesnt get to GoogleTransport.create() because there's no Google accounts on the emulator however the first log above is from the emulator. On Nexus S running stock 2.3.1 the Google account auth token is retrieved from AccountManager but then the Exception is thrown as seen in the second log above

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like your project references are messed up.  Try checking the library dependencies.

Comment: The classes are recognized at compile time in eclipse and throw no errors until runtime.  this leads me to believe the project references are ok.  Additionally, I reinstalled eclipse and created a fresh project, but no dice

Comment: I've seen similar behavior before and resolved it by making sure all my jar files were getting included and being copied over.  My hunch is that is where your issue is.  If you are comfortable with sharing the source tree, upload it to github or someplace and I'll try to resolve it.